# Update all the values of counts to add 2.822 between dates only using DAX

Tags: dax

I have a table with a column of values that I would like to update by adding 2.822 of between dates and need help writing this code.

Notes: ColumnName2 adds 2.822 everything, but I want it to add only between the dates. ColumnName1 is the original values column.

It adds 2.822 to all dates, but I only want it to add to what is in between dates, regardless of blank values.

Code:

```
    AddToColumnsBetweenDates =
    CALCULATE(SUM(TableName[ColumnName1)+TableName[ColumnName2],
    FILTER(TableName, 
    DATEDIFF(DATE(2 018,01,01), DATE(2018,12,31),DAY
```

Another one that I tried:

```
    AddToColumnsBetweenDates =
    CALCULATE(SUM(TableName[ColumnName1),
    FILTER(TableName, 

    SUM(TableName[Column1])+TableName
    [ColumnName2]&&
    DATEDIFF(DATE(2018,01,01) < TableName[ColumnName1]=BLANK(),
    DATE(2018,12,31),DAY) && TableName[ColumnName1]>=BLANK()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (Add1030ToEachNodeBefore2019 is the 2.822 variable), hence this adds to all the nodes that exist in 2018 only:

AddToNodesBetween2018StartAnd2018End = IF(Table[DateColumn.[Year]=2018, CALCULATE( SUMX(Table, Table[NodeCount]+Table[Add1030ToEachNodeBefore2019]), (DATESBETWEEN(Table[DateColumn].[Date], DATE(2018,01,01), DATE(2018,12,31)))), Table[NodeCount])